# It is about not all code paths return a value in the method Isnt

Tags: c#

[image]

> not all code paths return a value in the method Isnt

There is a problem with Isnt method. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why do you even use a `for` loop if you `return` the first time you enter it ?

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop, insert a new return statement to return a value if there is nothing to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

There are values for `a` (e.g. `a=2`) which will not hit your for loop, so no return statement will be hit in that case.

Also please post code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the method with a return type 'bool'. The compiler tries to check if a boolean value is actually returned from that method through all possible flows, **without being bound by any conditions**. Logically this method would work for all possible values, but you need to make the compiler understand that.

There's no need to put that extra check if(a<2), just scribble a 'return false' outside the for loop and you're good. That's probably a better way of coding.

'See the compiler helps you with your coding standard after all ;) '

Comment: Wrong : if `a == 2`, the method ends without reaching a `return` statement. See, the first `if` will be `false` and `Math.sqrt(2) < 2` so the `for` loop would never be entered, then you can't reach a `return`. (Same goes for 3)